# Does space have boundaries?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

In order for the big bang to happen there had to have been some sort of boundaries to contain enough force for an explosion a release of energy that large to have been capable of creating a universe. So is there some sort of boundary that will stop our expansion or will the universe just stop expanding after all the atoms are ripped apart from expanding?

Comment: It is not conceivable that such a massive, heated amount of matter as what created the universe, a planet, or a star could have spontaneously compressed into a small area. Thus there is no scientific explanation of how cosmology works. But this is a problem with science, not philosophy.

Comment: @DJSims Why would cosmology require that anything be spontaneously compressed? We have no reason to think such a compression ever occurred, as far as I know.

Comment: Exactly, it didn't, and science cannot explain star formation

Comment: @DJSims  That is a pretty outrageous claim.  Every astrophysicist would disagree.  On what do you base it?

Comment: Astrophysics is aware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is totally unclear which type of event is Big Bang, notably which concept of boundary applies to Big Bang.

Big Bang is an extrapolation from present cosmology into the past. But it is a limit point of our current models, not part of them.

Also the future of our world is unclear. Of course spacetime expands. According to latest observation the expansion rate is even increasing with time. But whether the expansion goes on forever or spacetime will recontract to a Big Bounce cannot yet be decided. These questions are linked to open questions concerning dark matter and dark energy.

A good introduction to cosmology is *Greene, Brian: The Fabric of the Cosmos* (2004)

Answer (score 0):

Your question actually touches on a more primitive and classical notion of two absolutes, namely Objects and Space - Epicurus.  Objects represent atoms, and Space is that one thing that is *not empty, nor full*.

Space contains all things - Thales.

To fathom space is to fill it with ideas, and from there forward it no longer is space.  But I do agree with Thales, it is the greatest thing as it contains all things.

Answer (score 0):

In the modern sense of the word 'boundary' it would be extremely counterintuitive for our space to have a boundary.

It would mean that somehow there would be place in space where there were directions in which you simply could not move because there is no more space in that direction.  The boundary of a disc is the circle that circumscribes it.  You cannot move outward from there and remain in the disc.  This seems to utterly defy our notion of space.

That does not mean that space is necessarily boundless.  A sphere or a torus has no boundary, but is not boundless, such things are limited in size.  The 'space' one occupies in video games like 'Asteroids' lacks boundary because it wraps, but it is finite in size.

It is most likely that our space is a closed manifold like a sphere or torus, only three dimensional.  This would allow it to have finite size, which it should, if it has been growing from a point source for a finite duration, without defying our notion of how space should act locally by having an actual boundary.